# FLUTTER: Blend imaged with Median Filter

Tags: image, flutter, camera, blend

i need to blend a lot of images taken with camera plugin (ui.Image format) using a median filter like in photoshop.

I currently usi canvas with drawImage and Paint.BlendMode (i'm using lighten which makes a kinda similar effect), but there is no "median" blend mode.

Median filter is done by taking a median value of every single channel RGB of all the images.

So... is there anything for median filter in dart/flutter, or i need to check manually all the image pixels? In this second case, how can i convert ui.Image in a class which allows me to get the single pixel and write it in another image?
Example:

```
color = image.getPixel(x, y);

newImage.setPixel(x, y, color);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60297917/192373) convert `ui.image` to RGB in flutter, but such manipulation will be prohibitively slow. You need some additional package, e.g. https://pub.dev/packages/photofilters or some [other](https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Aimage).

Comment: I didn't find anything with median filter on images :(

I tried with image package and getPixel/setPixel, but it needs 2 minutes just for 5 images to blend :( 

What i need is: 
For each pixel in the same coordinates for all images, i need to do an arithmetic mean fof each channel (R, G, and B), then write than pixel.
I currently add all red green and blu pixel in a List<int>, and then i do an arithmetic mean with:
int mediaR = red.reduce((a, b) => a + b) ~/ red.length;

Comment: But... results are perfect! but it's too slow, and the app is stuck meanwhile it loads. Maybe i can use isolate for avoid stuck, but it's slow anyway....

Comment: This is a kind of task that justifies [ffi](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop)